# Designing circle label with many attributes in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, digitizing, circle

Without using ArcPy, how can I create a circle label show many pieces of information from an attribute table in ArcGIS?

I have image about planning zone map, with specific label on top of objects, now I need digitizing map in ArcGIS.

[image: Planning label (note)]

Answer (score 1):

The comments contain two methods that seem reasonable to me:

- without ArcPy, [@Jakub has suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216383/designing-circle-label-with-many-attributes-in-arcgis-for-desktop/233555#comment331912_216383) that it may be:

> Possible with a combination of EMF graphic (or a vector symbol if you
>   can create one from that looks like this - tricky on other machines if
>   fonts are involved) and formatted text if all the source atributes are
>   in the feature class that's being labelled. Placement will not be
>   perfect if the features being labelled are polygons. You will of
>   course need to use a label expression with formatting tags.

- with ArcPy I think it should be possible to:

> to get a label point and convert it to page units, then to use graphic
>   and text elements to draw the "fancy" label offset from it. This would
>   be in layout view.